# How to display images from databes in device to viewpager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-sqlite, android-image

I'm trying for days to find out solution on internet but without success.

I would like to display images in viewpager using SQLite databases.

Does anyone have example I can use for help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your **image** is stored as a **Blob** type

```
byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(ImagesQuery.SRC);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Haven't tried it, but this should work.

Cheers, 
Sree